# Bytefield package

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am using `bytefield` as in the code below

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
   \begin{bytefield}{32}
      \bitheader[endianness=big]{0,22,23,30,31} \\
      \bitbox{1}{s} & \bitbox{8}{\textcolor{red}{E}} & \bitbox{23}{f - mantissa}
   \end{bytefield}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want to change the command `\bitheader` to show {0, 51, 52, 62, 63} using the same size as the previous picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature is not provided by the package `bytefield` as far as I could see.
There is a somewhat hackish solution. It catches the time, where the bit numbers are set and formatted via `\bf@bitformatting`. The bit number is stored in counter `header@val`. The hack changes the value locally for the numbers that should be replaced.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

  \begin{bytefield}{32}
    \bitheader[endianness=big]{0,22,23,30,31} \\
    \bitbox{1}{s} & \bitbox{8}{\textcolor{red}{E}}
    & \bitbox{23}{f - mantissa}
  \end{bytefield}

  \bigskip

  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \let\saved@bf@bitformatting\bf@bitformatting
    \renewcommand*{\bf@bitformatting}{%
      \ifnum\value{header@val}=22 %
        \value{header@val}=51 %
      \else\ifnum\value{header@val}=23 %
        \value{header@val}=52 %
      \else\ifnum\value{header@val}=30 %
        \value{header@val}=62 %
      \else\ifnum\value{header@val}=31 %
        \value{header@val}=63 %
      \fi\fi\fi\fi
      \saved@bf@bitformatting
    }%
    \begin{bytefield}{32}
      \bitheader[endianness=big]{0,22,23,30,31} \\
      \bitbox{1}{s} & \bitbox{8}{\textcolor{red}{E}}
      & \bitbox{23}{f - mantissa}
    \end{bytefield}
  \endgroup

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Indeed, Heiko, `bytefield` assumes "all the bits are of equal width".